# Java Search an array for a matching string

Tags: java, arrays, string, match

how can I optimize the following:

```
final String[] longStringArray = {"1","2","3".....,"9999999"};
String searchingFor = "9999998"
for(String s : longStringArray)
    {
        if(searchingFor.equals(s))
        {
            //After 9999998 iterations finally found it
            // Do the rest of stuff here (not relevant to the string/array)
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: The longStringArray is only searched once per runtime & is not sorted & is different every other time I run the program.

Im sure there is a way to improve the worst case performance here, but I cant seem to find it...

P.S. Also would appreciate a solution, where string searchingFor does not exist in the array longStringArray.

Thank you.

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve here. You can do everything with the string `searchingFor` what you can do with it's identical twin in the array. - A good solution has to know what you do next.

Comment: I wanted to increase performance.. and not search in linear time... I think its clear enough. The answer below said I can't improve that.

Comment: Yep, but it's not neccessarily true. Is I said, it depends what is your next step. For example: do you want to check if a value is inside the array? (HashSet) Or these strings are identifiers and you want to get an object they represent (HashMap). and so on... So it all depends on the bigger picture. - Also the ratio of your **searches / changes** matters much.

Comment: well, yes, as the code above - I want to see if the string is inside the array (I only want to search an array once per runtime, the array and the string changes the next time I search). What I do next has nothing to do with the search and only is performed if the string is there (e.g. the inside of the if statement is nonrelevant to the search). I can change the question, but I dont know how to improve it. please advice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, if you *have* to use an array, and you don't know if it's sorted, and you're only going to do one lookup, it's always going to be an O(N) operation. There's nothing you can do about that, because any optimization step would be at least O(N) to start with - e.g. populating a set or sorting the array.

Other options though:

- If the array is sorted, you could perform a binary search. This will turn each lookup into an O(log N) operation.
- If you're going to do more than one search, consider using a [`HashSet<String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). This will turn each lookup into an O(1) operation (assuming few collisions).

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
ArrayUtils.indexOf(array, string);
```

[ArrayUtils documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second array with the **hash codes** of the string and binary search on that.

You will have to sort the *hash array* and move the elements of the original array accordingly. This way you will end up with extremely fast searching capabilities but it's going to be kept ordered, so inserting new elements takes resources.

The most optimal would be implementing a **binary tree** or a **B-tree**, if you have really so much data and you have to handle inserts it's worth it.

Comment: Do you propose to reimplement a hashtable? Java has already an implementation in HashSet (for this case, other variants are HashMap/Hashtable/ConcurrentHashMap).

Comment: @Paŭlo If not for other reasons, you going to profit from it as a developer to write such things. And you're wrong about the suggested objects. All three of them create a key-value association. OP has only values as far as we can tell.

Comment: Of course a hash table could be reimplemented, but your variant (If I understand right) is a combination of sorted list and hashtable, and will not be much better than a simple sorted list (a bit better, since comparing hashcodes may be more efficient), and still has the problem of hash collisions of a hash table.

Comment: @Paŭlo It's basically an ordered list of hashes, so it's binsearch. Identical hashes will be found by checking *around* the result of binsearch and of course `equals` to make sure we have the right one. - The original elements have to be reordered to match the indexes of the hash array of course.

Comment: Yes, this way you throw away all the advantages of Hash tables, namely the (usual) O(1) access, and get to a O(log n) access. And constructing the table needs O(n log n) (at least) instead of O(n) for a hash table. It is an interesting thought, but not really a useful alternative to a real hashtable.

Comment: @Paŭlo You have interesting points. I will check out the actual implementation of hash-based containers in Java API.

Comment: The important idea of a hash table is that we can use the hash code of a key to directly (i.e. in O(1) time) get the index in some array, and not have to search. Then collision management is the only hairy point. (And of course, resizing.)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList(longStringArray).contains(searchingFor)